# Static in ObjC vs Static in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm trying to instantiate a DateFormatter only once for the class, so I don't waste a bunch of computing time doing it for every instance. In Obj-C I lazily instantiate a static property to accomplish this. I'm trying to figure out how to do this in Swift and most of the explanations I've read don't exactly answer this question.

In Obj-C:

```
- (NSDateFormatter *)dateFormatter {
    static NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = nil;
    if (!dateFormatter) {
        dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;
    }
    return dateFormatter;
}
```

Swift translation?

```
static var dateFormatter: DateFormatter {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium
    return dateFormatter
}
```

Comment: You can let the compiler infer the enumeration: `dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare the static variable at the class level:

```
class MyClass {
    static var dateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = DateFormatter.Style.medium
        return dateFormatter
    }()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A lazy initialized static **constant** without using `self` in Swift is

```
static let dateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium
    return dateFormatter
}()
```

The same code (without `static`) as instance property is also a constant but won't be initialized lazily.

However the `static` keyword in the ObjC code is a bit misleading. The 1:1 equivalent to the ObjC code is

```
lazy var dateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium
    return dateFormatter
}()
```

The variable is initialized lazily but is an **instance** property.

Comment: so, I use the lazy notation, but not the lazy keyword?

Comment: From the documentation: *Stored type properties are lazily initialized on their first access. They are guaranteed to be initialized only once, even when accessed by multiple threads simultaneously, and they do not need to be marked with the lazy modifier.* Type properties are the `static` ones.

Comment: Sorry, I'm just not that familiar with the terminology. Are you saying what I'm trying to create is a 'stored type' property? This is created with this syntax, and I the only thing 'static' does is make it lazy to when the class is first created/called, instead of at launch?

Comment: PS: A property initialized with a closure is a stored property by definition.

Comment: static in obj-c, even within a method, means it only gets assigned once for the app, that's what my obj-c code is doing. is that what the second block of code you have is really doing? It looks like that would be per instance. It seems the first block of code you have, with the static keyword present, is probably what I want?

Comment: Once again, the second `lazy var` example does exactly behave like the Objective-C code. `static` in Swift means it's a type / class object, a *constant* in Swift is `let`. However a closure in a variable declaration is executed only once.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I do appreciate it, also I think we had a miscommunication. I was interested in the memory management aspect of the obj-c code more than if it is or is not instantiated lazily. Your `lazy var` example accomplishes the lazy part correctly, but it creates a new dateFormatter for every instance of the class, therefore it is not the 1:1 equivalent of my Obj-C example, which only allocated memory for the dateFormatter once for the lifetime of the app.

Comment: OK, from this point of view the `static let` is the corresponding code, but it has to be called on the class ( which would be `+` in ObjC)

Answer (score 0):

Further to the answer by @CodeDifferent, you might want to wrap the static in a `class var` as this will allow you to override the date formatter in a subclass:

```
class MyClass {

    fileprivate static let mediumDateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium
    return dateFormatter
    }()

    class var dateFormatter: DateFormatter  {
       return mediumDateFormatter
    }
}

class MyOtherClass: MyClass {

    fileprivate static let shortDateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = .short
        return dateFormatter
    }()

   override class var dateFormatter: DateFormatter  {
        return shortDateFormatter
    }      
}
```